# Altair's counterpart to ggplots geom_segment

Tags: python, ggplot2, data-visualization, diagram, altair

In pythons data-visualization package altair I am stuck with mark_bar.
It seems that mark_bar can handle only discrete values on at least one axis.
I want however a behavior that is similar to geom_segment in ggplot, in other words the possibility to draw horizontal lines, specifing the x-begin, x-end and a height on y, like that:
[image: Example]

As you can see, the segments can also overlap, which is what I want.
Using altair, I nearest I get is using mark_bar like that:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

 source = pd.DataFrame([
{"importance": "1.2", "start": 1, "end": 3},
{"importance": "10", "start": 8, "end": 10},
{"importance": "1", "start": 3, "end": 8}
])

 alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
x='start',
x2='end',
y='importance'
)
```

which gives:

[image: Altair example]

When I set
`y='importance:Q'`

it does not work as expected, instead I get:

[image: Altair example 2]

A part from this problem I really love altairs simplicity and I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With quantitative encodings on both axes, the default bar orientation is `"vertical"`. You can change this with the `orient` property, and you can adjust the thickness of horizontal bars with the `height` property:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame([
  {"importance": "1.2", "start": 1, "end": 3},
  {"importance": "10", "start": 8, "end": 10},
  {"importance": "1", "start": 3, "end": 8}
])

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar(
  orient='horizontal',
  height=20
).encode(
  x='start:Q',
  x2='end:Q',
  y='importance:Q'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you were faster than me and you're answer is also better!

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself:

```
source = pd.DataFrame([
{"importance": "1.2", "start": 1, "end": 3 ,"i":2.2},
{"importance": "10", "start": 8, "end": 10, "i": 11},
{"importance": "1", "start": 2, "end": 8,"i": 2}
])

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
x='start:Q',
x2='end:Q',
y='importance:Q',
y2 ='i:Q'
)
```

So it is enough to add a column which is a copy of "importance" plus some offset that represents the thickness of the bars.